# confirm box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create one customized confirm box in jQuery with two buttons(OK , Save)
If user press OK, two javascript functions in order should be called and executed, if user press Save just one js function should be called.
Now my question:

how can I call one js function inside the dialoge of confirm box.

this is my code

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
  .html('<div><h6>If you Click on OK,you willaccept modifications and close the activity, click on Save means: only acceptance without closure the activity?</h6></div>')
  .dialog({
      modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto', resizable: false,
      buttons: {
          OK: function () {
              f1();    // How can I call it...my question is from syntax problem
              f2();    // How can I call it...my question is from syntax problem
              $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          Save: function () {
              f1();    // How can I call it...my question is from syntax problem
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      }

});
```

as you maybe understand my problem is syntax of this calling.let me tell you f1() and f2() are two javascript function which have defined and implemented.

Thanks in advance

---

Now I have another Question from this dialog..I want to get response from this dialoge...Let me copy my code maybe in this way you can understand more.

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')

      .html('<div><h6><fmt:message key="message" /></h6></div>')
      .dialog({
          modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
          width: 'auto', resizable: false,
          buttons: {
              OK: function () {
                    close='yes';
                    arg="&accept_op_id="+op_id+"&tat="+tat+"&acdd="+acdd+"&ente="+ente+"&fdd="+fdd+"&aed="+aed+"&add="+add+"&close="+close;
                    openSched('piano',arg,'non_sched');

              },
              Save: function () {
                  close='no';
                  arg="&accept_op_id="+op_id+"&tat="+tat+"&acdd="+acdd+"&ente="+ente+"&fdd="+fdd+"&aed="+aed+"&add="+add+"&close="+close;
                    openSched('piano',arg,'non_sched');

              }
          }
    });
```

I want to say: if user clicked on OK,one variable which is called 'close' is assigned yes and then one function (openSched()) will be called with this close value....If user clicked on Save , close =no

How can I do that...do you see one syntax problem??
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Based on what you've provided, that should work.  What actually happens when you run the code as-is?

Comment: when Ipress the Save button , it does not do anything

Comment: "Save" isn't a standard button name/type I don't think, so try wrapping it in quotes to specify that it's custom text. ie: `"Save": function () {`.  Or define the buttons' properties more specifically, as laid out in the jQuery UI [Dialog docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/dialog/#option-buttons).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
      modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto', resizable: false,
      buttons: {
      OK: function () {
          f1();    
          f2();    
          $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Save: function () {
          f1();    
          $(this).dialog("close");
      }}
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

}); 

function f1()
{
    alert("f1 called");
}

function f2()
{
    alert("f2 called");
}

<div id="dialog"><h6>If you Click on OK,you willaccept modifications and close the activity, click on Save means: only acceptance without closure the activity?</h6></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLxksjqx/5/)**

```
     $("<div></div>").appendTo("body").html("<div title='You Title here' class='newDiv'><h6>If you Click on OK, you will accept modifications and close the activity, <br/><br/> Click on Save means: only acceptance without closure the activity?</h6></div>").find(".newDiv").dialog({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        click: function () {
            fnOnOkay();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, {
        text: "Save",
        click: function () {
            fnOnSave();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});

function fnOnOkay() {
    fnOne();
    fnTwo();}

function fnOnSave() {
    console.log("Call one on save clicked");}

function fnOne() {
    console.log("Call one on OK clicked");}

function fnTwo() {
    console.log("Call Two on OK clicked");}
```